# Octave integer matrix

Tags: c++, octave

I'm not able to create an integer matrix using Octave in my cpp code. I'm using the following code-

```
intNDArray< octave_int<short> > matrix_int8 =intNDArray(iRows,iCols);
for (r=0;r<iRows;r++)
{
  for(c=0;c<iCols;c++)
  {
    matrix_int8(r,c)=(pcData[r]+c);  
  }
}
```

I get the following error-

```
error: missing template arguments before '(' token 
intNDArray< octave_int<short> > matrix_int8 =intNDArray(iRows,iCols);
```

Is this the right way to create an integer matrix? How should I declare an integer matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify template parameters after `intNDArray` in assignment.

```
intNDArray< octave_int<short> > matrix_int8 =intNDArray< octave_int<short> >(iRows,iCols);
```

Alternatively, you could just write:

```
intNDArray< octave_int<short> > matrix_int8(iRows,iCols);
```

Comment: @Misha it might be even simpler to use the `int8NDArray`, `int16NDArray`, etc typedefs